# instr() function SQLITE for Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, function

I wanna do the following on my existing sqlite database on android which is kind a built like that
colomns: id --- rule --- path --- someotherdata

A rule now e.g. contains a part of a filename (either just some trivial stuff like "mypicture" or also a filetype like "jpg"). Now what I want to do is, I want to write a query, which gets my all rules, which contain a part of an inputstring. 
I have tried following example: String value = "somepicturefilename.jpg"

my statement:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES + " WHERE instr('"+ value + "',rule)!=0 ORDER BY " + KEY_ID+ " DESC;"
```

the statement is in java so the "value" should get inserted in the statement.

However, this does not work. I am not too familiar with sql nor sqlite, does anyone have a tip= ;) thanks.

edit: i've also tried charindex, which didn't work either.

edit: so a more detailed example.
following database is given.

```
id --- rule ---
1      "jpg"
2     "ponies"
3     "gif"
4     "pdf"
```

Now the user enters a filename. Let's say "poniesAsUnicorns.jpg". So "poniesAsUnicorns.jpg" is my input string and the query should match both id#1 and id#2 because "poniesAsUnicorns.jpg" contains both "jpg" and "ponies"

I hope that clarifies what I want.

edit:
here is what i tried too:

```
String statement = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES
            + " WHERE charindex(rule,'" + value
            + "') > 0 ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC;";
```

but throws a "no such operation" exception.

Comment: If you add a more detailed example of what you have and what you expect it would be easier to answer

Comment: added one. thanks for your engagement.

Comment: is this crashing or simply not returning any result?  Is there any message in logcat?

Comment: instr throws a sql exception that there is no such operation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `instr()` is not available, so you can use:

```
select * from table where replace("poniesAsUnicorns.jpg", rule, "") != "poniesAsUnicorns.jpg";
```

or for case insensitive matches:

```
select * from table where replace(upper("poniesAsUnicorns.jpg"), upper(rule), "") != upper("poniesAsUnicorns.jpg");
```

Comment: hah that seems to do the job! do you have an idea if it's casesensitive?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES + " WHERE rule LIKE '%"+ value + "%' ORDER BY " + KEY_ID+ " DESC;"
```

try this one.

Comment: I've already tried this. But I basically need it the other way round. the thing is... the column needs to be a part of (e.g. is smaller than)  the input string.
see:
04-24 00:37:38.057: D/RulesHelper(21328): found 0 entries by attribute:SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rules WHERE rule LIKE '%IMG_20130418_123133.jpg%' ORDER BY id DESC;

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore(_) in the LIKE pattern instead of percentage(%). Underscore will matches any single character in the value instead of the entire string sequence.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES + " WHERE rule LIKE '_"+ value + "_' ORDER BY " + KEY_ID+ " DESC;"
```

[LIKE operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

Comment: that didn't do the job, because as I said, I would need it the other way round kinda.

04-24 09:23:28.555: D/RulesHelper(4399): found 0 entries by attribute:SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rules WHERE rule LIKE '_IMG_20130418_124142.jpg_' ORDER BY id DESC;

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your SQL expression ... the only thing that might be killing it is the lack of spaces around the inequality operator `!=`

Try this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES + " WHERE instr('"+ value + "',rule) > 0 ORDER BY " + KEY_ID+ " DESC;"
```

I'm not sure if the SQLite implementation in Android is complete, you may find that some ops don't work, so do some simple tests as a sanity check.

If that doesn't work you can reverse the condition.

```
[field]='some_value'
```

is just as valid as:

```
'some_value'=[field]
```

So in your example I thought you should be able to do something like:

```
select distinct * from TABLE_RULES
where 'poniesAsUnicorns.jpg' like '%' + rule + '%';
```

I tested this in mySQL and it doesn't like the `+` concatenation but it does work happily like this:

```
select distinct * from TABLE_RULES
where 'poniesAsUnicorns.jpg' like replace('%rule%','rule',rule);
```

Comment: I've just tried your SQL query in [SQLite manager](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) and it seems fine ... I'm stumped as to why this wouldn't be valid in Android

Comment: hey. I have tried your statements. the "like" one didn't work because i guess it took "rule" as a string and not as a field. 
the "like replace" thingy, I didn't understand at all... what should this do? replace the word role in a rule with the field rule? Oo

Comment: exactly ... it strips out the word rule from the first part and inserts your field value (also called rule) into the gap.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_RULES + " WHERE '" + value + "' like '%' || rule || '%' ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC;"
```