# Delete number from all contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

The following query fails and I am not sure why. It is supposed to delete all numbers occuring in the string list passed to the method. I first suspected the MIME type but leaving out *" LIKE ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"* wouldn't solve it either.

```
public static void deleteAllNumbersFromAllContacts(final Context context, final List<String> numbers) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                for (String number : numbers) {

                    number = PhoneNumberUtil.toE164(number);

                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                            .newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withSelection(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = ?",
                                    new String[] { "%" + number + "%",
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }).build());
                }
                context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the format of the telephone numbers in the Android db and in your argument. Its not uncommon that the numbers in Android are being saved with whitespaces (i.e. +12 345 678 910). With your above query you wouldn't match numbers without whitespaces.

To get around that ambiguity you can use functions like REPLACE directly in the query: [instr() function SQLITE for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180117/instr-function-sqlite-for-android) .

So your function could turn out to look like this:

```
public static void deleteAllNumbersFromAllContacts(final Context context, final List<String> numbers) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                for (String number : numbers) {

                  number = PhoneNumberUtil.toE164(number);

                  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(
                      "REPLACE(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                        + ", ' ', '') LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + number + "%" }).build());
                }
                context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Howto overcome this? Do I have to query for all numbers, do on each the trim in Java, compare to my searched number, store the id, if matching and then delete? Seems like a lot of overhead to me. Isn't there a shortcut?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180117/instr-function-sqlite-for-android . Added it to my answer