# SQLiteException: no such function: INSTR (code 1) under android 4.44

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I find the issue when my device is under 4.4.4 , i can't get it why the issue will happen like this.  I try to find some solution [Why does SQLite say that instr doesnt exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887558/why-does-sqlite-say-that-instr-doesnt-exist) , so i guess there was no `INSTR` before when android device version is under 4.4.4

In my case i use the sql like this:
//Sort date : Latest to Old date

```
public List<Contact> sortingDate() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " ORDER BY\n" +
            "    SUBSTR(Date, 1, 4) DESC,\n" +
            "    CASE WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') = 2\n" +
            "         THEN '0' || SUBSTR(Date, 6, 1)\n" +
            "         ELSE SUBSTR(Date, 6, 2) END DESC,\n" +
            "    CASE WHEN LENGTH(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)) = 1\n" +
            "         THEN '0' || SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)\n" +
            "         ELSE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1) END DESC; ", null);
    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setBeforeMorning(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setAfterMorning(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setBeforeNoon(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setAfterNoon(cursor.getString(5));
            contact.setBeforeNight(cursor.getString(6));
            contact.setAfterNight(cursor.getString(7));
            System.out.println("The result is :" + cursor.getString(1));
            //Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

I use the sql because i want to `ORDERBY` my date is `yyyy/mm/dd` if my date is like `2017/2/5`

Now i get the issue , i don't know how to change my code if i can't use `INSTR` anymore.

I looking for some answer say can use `LIKE '%Date%'` , obviously its not suitable for my case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16180907/1061944

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't know how to use replace in my case , can you give me some tips ? Thanks you.

Comment: You are looking for the index of the occurrence, unfortunately in sqlite not supported. I advise you handle that at the application level.

Comment: Oh no, it should  have another way i don't find it :(